# Accidental short circuit of lead acid battery, can I still use it / charge it?

Tags: battery-charging, lead-acid

Just a minute ago I accidentally short circuited my lead acid battery. The wiring touched, glowed bright, the plastic around it melted and smoke got released, but I'm not sure from the battery or from the plastic. It smelled like plastic burning, so I'm hoping the latter.

The battery discharged quite a lot and the voltage dropped from ~12.80 volt to around ~12.55 volt.

However, this short circuit lasted only a fraction of a second, the wires only touched and they almost immediately lost contact. The battery seems to still be working, but I'm not sure if it's safe to charge.

Is it safe to assume I can still use it properly? It's the first time I short circuited something like this and it scared me a bit ha.

Comment: Likely depends on its discharge rating and the amps that you drew from it.

Comment: Almost certainly ok.

Comment: I'm using this battery: http://www.batterysales.nl/files/Loodaccu_Ultracell_12v_1.3ah_UL1.3-12_VDS.pdf

Comment: I have no idea what amps I drew from it. It wasn't connected to any other circuit as I just took it out of the charger. Because I'm prototyping I attach wires to it to insert it into a breadboard and those touched for a split second.

Comment: If it dropped below 11V I might be worried, but 0.5V drop isn't very much. Starting an engine would draw more current. The wire would vaporize before ruining the battery IMO.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your answers. I had the same logic with the voltage drop.

Comment: Now I've connected it to the circuit properly and voltage seems to be dropping quite fast, faster than before... Perhaps I didn't charge it long enough, perhaps a cell is busted. I don't know...

Answer (score 2):

Probably okay.

Consider using a fuse, ideally a fuse right at the terminal or inline as close as possible or a short length of "fusible link".

A good practice to get into.

Comment: Only now, when I've connected it to my circuit, properly this time, the voltage seems to drop rapidly. Like really fast. Could one of the cells be damaged?

Comment: Could it be that one of the cells is damaged? The voltage is 0.2V in less than half an hour. Normal for my circuit is 0.2V drop per 1.5 hours.

Answer (score 2):

If you used such a thin wire that you can connect to a breadboard then I think that incident isn't that "short" circuit, from the battery's point of view. The wire resistance is enough to limit the current, perhaps 10..20A or so flown for a fraction of second, it is pretty normal for these SLA batteries.

Next time it is a good idea to add a fuse as close as possible to the battery terminal, **and** use a fuse that not just blows when the wires already red hot, use one which is **rated** for the application.

Short circuits not only happen mechanically by accidents, anything wrong can happen in the circuit you experimenting with. This is especially true in prototyping.

It is also a good safety practice to always disconnect any power if you leave the area. Always. The sole exception is long-term testing, but that should be done after thorough pre-testing and already thought out and operational safety systems. The bigger the power you working with the importace (and complexity, cost...) of the safety systems gets more and more significant.

Answer (score 1):

You're ok to continue using the battery.

Typical 12 volt lead-acid car batteries can be discharged to about 9 volts and be recharged, so you're in the clear.  Discharging a lead-acid car battery below 9 volts reduces the battery's capacity but it doesn't cause explosion or anything dangerous like that.  Cars pulls hundreds of amps and their batteries aren't exploding.

I'm guessing your wires didn't make very good contact otherwise they would have welded together.  This can be dangerous and you should be careful of this.  If the wire is thick enough, it will weld and stick.  If it is thinner, it will weld and then melt away, like a fuse.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a such wire can draw at most 50 amps for two or three seconds before melting, but a car starter can draw from 90 to 150 amps, depending of the type, so for me the only risk is that molten metal touches the battery case and penetrates the battery, making an internal short circuit.